# What is the name of monodevelop on Kali?

Tags: package-management, kali-linux, mono

On a Kali Linux terminal, running `apt-get install monodevelop` I get

> E: Invalid operation install

What is the correct package name I need to use in order to install monodevelop?

Answer (score 0):

The package [`monodevelop`](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/monodevelop) is available on the kali linux repository

You should have the following line in your [sources.list](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Edit your `sources.list`:

Open the terminal an run the following command:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Verify if the URL exist , if not add it:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Press Ctrl + o then hit Enter , Ctrl +x

To install the package run:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install monodevelop
apt install --fix -broken
```

[Update:](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/monodevelop)

> The package monodevelop 5.10.0.871-2 has been removed from kali-rolling.

Comment: it there a way to install it without internet connection? to download the files from another kali and move the file to vm and install it?

Comment: You cannot install the package without intenet connexion because `monodevelop` require a lot of dependencies .